# Что читать по сетевым технологиям?

Tags: сеть, книги, faq

Всем привет!
У меня несколько нетривиальный вопрос, постараюсь кратко объяснить суть.

Изначально у меня возникло желание обучиться программированию, что я и делаю изучая python.

Однако мне кажется что для полного понимания той части IT, которая меня интересует, мне необходимо знание технологий клиент-сервер, принципы построения сетевой архитектуры и т.д.

С чего начать изучение этой области? Условно говоря, для начала я хочу понять что такое DNS-адреса, IP-адреса,домены,сервера, и т.д., однако не по частям, а иметь системное представление об этих вещах.

Что стоит почитать?

Comment: OSI, легко гуглится.

Comment: Есть класная серия статей http://linkmeup.ru/blog/11.html

Comment: Всем спасибо за ответы!
Решил начать с Таненбаума, кажется он наиболее полный.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Только классика, только хардкор

[image]
[image]

*Серьезно, отличные книги.*

Comment: По поводу хардкора - можно почитать обучающие материалы от Cisco. Весьма неплохо написано, достаточно подробно жуются сложные примеры. Изложение кумулятивное от простого к сложному и без лишнего словоблудия.

Answer (score 6):

Рекомендую "Компьютерные сети" Олиферов. Материал изложен последовательно, подробно. Не составит труда изучить сети по этой книге. Если не ошибаюсь, сейчас актуально 4 издание.

Answer (score 2):

Чтобы "понять, что такое DNS, IP и так далее", нужно также обладать некоторым минимумом знаний и навыков о современных IT вообще - ведь сети "сами по себе" не существуют, они являются частью каких-то бОльших систем.

Чтобы не метаться по горам образовательных материалов на тему "современных IT вообще", я попытался собрать их [список в пригодном для последовательного изучения порядке](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/422226/). Посмотрите, может пригодится.

Answer (score 2):

- Олифер В.Г., Олифер Н.А. "Компьютерные сети. Принципы, технологии, протоколы"
- Таненбаум Э. "Компьютерные сети"
- Хант К. "TCP/IP. Сетевое администрирование"