# Что нужно знать сисадмину о UNIX-like мире?

Tags: unix

Что должен знать и уметь системный администратор, претендующий на уверенное понимание основ мира UNIX-like?

Вопрос можно трактовать и как "список для изучения для новичка, стремящегося стать профи", и как "куда копать уже опытному сисдамину, обошедшему в своей карьере UNIX-like стороной".

Comment: UNIX мир слишком огромен, чтобы полностью осознать его в одиночку.  Выхлоп `apropos . | nl | more` как бы намекает нам на это.

Comment: И тем не менее - далеко не все профи имеют за плечами университетское образование, связанное с компьютерами (некоторые вообще никакого не имеют). И ничего, вполне себе комфортно ориентируются в Unix-мире. Так что направления для самообразования указывать можно и нужно.

Comment: Там в 11.0 CURRENT ветке FreeBSD сейчас 13595535 строк кода только на ядро и окружение не считая портов. Сомневаюсь что в этом мире есть хоть один человек который *комфортно* ориентируется в этом поражающим воображение коллективном месиве. Также в эпичный список внизу стоит первым пунктом добавить [ТБ в случае пожара в комнате со стойками](http://serverfault.com/questions/496139/something-is-burning-in-the-server-room-how-can-i-quickly-identify-what-it-is).

Comment: Вы путаете "комфортно ориентироваться" (знать базовые сущности и куда копать в случае необходимости) и "знать назубок от и до". Или мы говорим на разных языках. Или Вы просто троллите. Может, у Вас есть идея, как переформулировать вопрос, чтобы он звучал логичнее/уместнее?

Comment: Да не троллю же, зачем? Просто поделился мнением о его огромности. Эта штука старше меня почти в два раза. А по поводу уместности, так вопрос вроде нормальный же. vi(m)/emacs еще можно добавить туда, чтобы конфиги редактировать быстро.

Comment: Оно там есть: "vi/vim: редактировать файлы..."

Answer (score 15):

Этот список я составил, чтобы давать на него ссылку коллегам, спрашивающим "а что нужно изучить, чтобы начать разбираться в Linux (или FreeBSD) на крутом уровне?". Я постарался охватить максимально широкий круг минимально необходимых навыков и знаний, обладая которыми системный администратор сможет самостоятельно разобраться в практически любой задаче, связанной с администрированием UNIX-like операционных систем и всего того, что их окружает.

Данный список не должен восприниматься как "минимальный набор, без которого в бой нельзя" - на полное его освоение может уйти значительное время, от нескольких месяцев до года, в зависимости от начального уровня и рвения обучающегося.

Там, где это было возможно без вреда для группировки пунктов, я сортировал их от простого к сложному. В сущности, изучать пункты списка можно именно в той последовательности, в которой они приведены.

Дополнения приветствуются.

**Набор базовых навыков и знаний о мире UNIX-like для системного администратора**

POSIX и другие стандарты и базовые сущности

- man, man sections
- PCRE, BRE/ERE
- UNIX timestamp, tzdata, leap seconds
- posix shell (signals, exit codes, pid, kill)
- locales
- runlevels
- UNIX sockets

Работа с файловой системой

- ОС Linux: структура каталогов, что где лежит и почему
- ОС Linux: типичные места расположения лог-файлов, pid-файлов
- файловая система: inode, stat, манипуляции временем изменения файла
- монтирование файловых систем, fstab, ro/rw режимы, noexec, noatime
- последствия неправильного размонтирования файловых систем, fsck
- жесткие и символические ссылки, разыменовывание файлов, восстановление удаленного файла
- монтирование iso-образов
- монтирование cifs/smb шар

Работа с блочными устройствами

- файловая система devfs: логические абстракции, разница/схожесть устройств и файлов
- блочные устройства null и zero
- блочные устройства random и urandom
- работа с dd: бэкап MBR, уничтожение информации на дисках, низкоуровневый перенос разделов
- создание ISO-образов, создание загрузочных флешек

Разграничение пользовательского доступа

- файловая система: права доступа и их изменение (chmod, chown)
- системные пользователи и группы (uid, gid, umask)
- суперпользователь: зачем нужен, что может, когда не нужно им пользоваться
- создание/удаление пользователей, создание/удаление групп, присвоение групп
- сброс пароля пользователю, принуждение пользователя к смене своего пароля
- работа с sudo, настройка sudoers
- setuid bit

Общие навыки работы в командной строке

- физические/виртуальные консоли, безопасность при работе в физической консоли
- sysrq
- login shell, interactive shell, shebang
- cat, echo
- environment и работа с переменными, export, env
- работа с файлами (создание/удаление/перенос/копирование), файловые маски
- работа с логикой (логические и бинарные операторы and, or, xor, not)
- стандартные потоки данных, их подавление и перенаправления, pipeline
- ^z, bg/fg, nohup
- bash: рекурсивный поиск по хистори, дополнение команд
- шорткаты: ^l, ^d, ^w, ^k, <kbd>esc</kbd>+<kbd>backspace</kbd>, работа с буфером обмена в консоли, скроллинг
- терминальные мультиплексоры: screen, tmux
- nice, renice
- cron/crontab/periodic
- способы выключить/ребутнуть машину вежливо/немедленно, shutdown в определенное время

Инструменты командной строки

- find: находить файлы по имени, типу, по дате создания/модификации, по совокупности параметров
- grep: поиск файлов по содержимому, поиск строк, содержащихся/не содержащихся в файле/потоке
- vi/vim: редактировать файлы, искать и заменять в них куски текста
- sed: массовая замена строк в файлах
- awk: манипуляции со столбцами в лог-файлах
- циклы, перебор, jot
- more/less, head/tail, cut
- diff
- хэш-функции (md5, sha(1|256|512))
- top, ps, df, du, who, id
- iconv

Работа с ядром

- версионирование ядра Linux
- пересборка/обновление ядра
- динамически загружаемые модули
- strace/ptrace (ktrace, dtrace)

Работа с приложениями

- общее понимание инфраструктуры приложений: shared libraries, зависимости, dependency hell, статическая сборка
- установка, обновление и удаление пакетов с помощью пакетного менеджера
- какой файл будет исполнен при запуске в консоли `commandname`?
- разрешение конкретному пользователю запускать конкретные команды через sudo
- установка (downgrade) пакетов версии более старой, чем доступна в пакетном менеджере
- сборка из исходных кодов (например, поставить из исходников php 5.2 на систему с установленным в виде пакета php 5.(3|4|5)
- патчи: просмотр изменений, применение, создание
- самостоятельная сборка пакетов, бэкпортирование

Теория и протоколы

- TCP/IP triple handshake (tcpdump), SYN-flood атаки
- UDP spoofing
- как работает DNS (dig), DNS-amplification атаки
- как работает HTTP 1.0/1.1 (telnet)
- как работают SMTP, POP, IMAP (telnet)
- DNSSEC, SPF, DKIM

Работа с сетью и удаленный доступ

- диагностика: ping, arping, traceroute, mtr
- ssh: создание (ssh-keygen) и распространение (ssh-copy-id) ключей, авторизация по ключам, основные ключи командной строки (-2, -4, -i), удалённое исполнение кода, проброс stdin/out, ssh-agent, autossh
- scp: передача файлов через ssh в обе стороны, основные ключи командной строки (-С, -с)
- туннелирование (ключи -R, -L), socks-proxy, проброс ssh-agent
- proxy-серверы (HTTP(S), SOCKS)
- TOR
- VPN (openvpn, ipsec)
- проброс X-сервера
- vnc
- доступ на windows-машины с unix-машин

Работа с архивами

- уметь создавать и распаковывать .tar, .tar.(gzip|bzip2), .zip, .rar
- уметь распаковывать не весь архив, а только нужную его часть

Безопасность

- способы передачи паролей и другой конфиденциальной информации по открытым каналам связи
- HTTPS и SSL сертификаты: теория, виды сертификатов, отличия SSL и TLS
- знаменитые уязвимости openssl и bash
- gnupg - шифрование файлов, проверка подписей, реализация pgp для электронной почты

Немного разработки

- VCS: subversion, git
- семантическое версионирование
- управление конфигурациями и деплой: Salt, Chef, Capistrano
- HTML и CSS на базовом уровне
- синтаксис разметки: wiki, markdown
- sh/bash для написания скриптов с простой логикой
- python/perl/ruby/php для высокоуровневых задач
- SQL для работы с большими порциями нормализованных данных
- блок-схемы для визуализации алгоритмов

Веб

- apache 1.x/2.x, ngnix/lighttpd, проксирующие схемы с несколькими веб-серверами
- php как модуль, как cgi/fcgi, php-fpm
- HTTP-flood атаки, атака медленного чтения
- чем опасны frame/iframe в HTML
- XSS/CSRF
- SQL injections
- MITM, HSTS

Железо

- общие представления о серверных платформах: rack unit, многопроцессорные системы, блейд-системы, внутренние интерфейсы (соединения)
- RAM: registered/unregistered, ECC, ранки (ранги)
- HDD: SATA/SCSI/SAS
- SSD: TRIM (discard)
- software RAID / hardware RAID
- iKVM/IPMI/BMC
- диагностика и выявление аппаратных сбоев для RAM и HDD
- общие представления об устройстве машинного зала ЦОДа, схемах электропитания (АВР/ДГУ/ИБП), технике безопасности при работе в серверной
- электрика: виды и назначение заземления, закон Ома, активная/реактивная нагрузка, расчет энергопотребления

Коммуникация

- базовый технический английский для чтения документации и материалов в интернете
- базовый технический английский для задавания вопросов и составления баг-репортов в интернете
- ознакомиться с документом How To Ask Questions The Smart Way
- теория работы со списками рассылок
- минимум по одному вопросу, возникающему в процессе (само)обучения, задать и решить с помощью maillist, с помощью stackexchange

Ссылки

- [What every computer science major should know](http://matt.might.net/articles/what-cs-majors-should-know/)
- [Похожий вопрос (несколько более широко поставленный) на английском языке](https://serverfault.com/questions/9766/)

Comment: Ого, потрясающий список. Останусь-ка я лучше на винде.

Comment: @VladD Аналогичный список для Windows-администратора будет наполовину идентичен (безопасность, разработка, веб, железо, коммуникация), наполовину состоять из windows-аналогов (не всегда более простых для самостоятельного изучения!) приведённых здесь *nix-решений. Плюс специфичные для Windows вещи, такие как базовое понимание принципов лицензирования ПО Microsoft по программам Open License и SPLA. Поправьте, если я принципиально ошибаюсь.

Comment: Ну, это был как бы юмор. Сисадмину и правда нужно знать много всего (и мне кажется, чистых Unix- или Windows-администраторов не бывает).

Comment: Капец, это случайно не вы этот список для программистов составляли?
http://zenden.ws/ru/blog/2015/05/03/chto-doljen-znat-c-programmist-8

Comment: Нет, я абсолютно не знаком с плюсами =)

Comment: "восстановление удаленного файла" -- это о бэкапах? А от упоминания о необходимости помнить закон Ома я просто чуть со стула не упал.

Comment: Нет, это про иноды - когда ни одного хардлинка на файл нет, `ls` его не показывает, но данные на диске всё ещё существуют, потому что какой-либо процесс "держит" иноду. Закон Ома нужно понимать, чтобы не путать вольтамперы с ваттами, и вычислять максимальную мощность оборудования, которое можно запитать линией, в разрыв которой установлен предохранитель на 16 А.

Comment: А, inode... Тогда лучше написали бы про `man fuser`.

Comment: Было бы замечательно, если бы Вы снабдили данный пост ссылками на литературу, которую считаете полезной, а потом превратили этот ответ в wiki.

Comment: И здесь тоже напомню про возможность принять свой ответ )

Comment: @nick-volynkin а стоит ли? Ответ не закрывает вопрос полностью. Кто-нибудь может когда-то дать ответ и получше.

Answer (score 3):

Я бы наверное составил списочек попроще:

1. Самое важное умение работать с консоли. Знание различных шеллов, ну хотя бы злосчастный `bash`. В Windows мире все можно сделать в GUI, в Unix мире не так, скорее даже наоборот в GUI почти ничего нельзя сделать, а вот с консоли пожалуйста.
2. Важное отличие Unix мира от мира остального мира: в Unix'е многое построено на перенаправлении потоков, фильтра и проч. радости консольной жизни. Ничто так не радует глаз как строка типа:
   `find . -name '*.java' -print0 | xargs -0 grep 'bingo' > output.txt`
3. Надо уметь пользоваться редактором [vi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vi)  (то бишь *visual editor*), без него будет трудновато конфигурить настройки разных прог.

Если вы поймете как все это работает, то остальное уже будет проще: `man` вам поможет.

Паттерн то простой. Допустим вы хотите сконфигурировать прокси. Берем для примера популярный у юниксоидов `squid`. Погружаемся в мануалы (то есть вызываем `man squid`), устанавливаем, конфигурируем его - вот где нужен `vi` :)

Запускаем его с тучей ключей, типа:

```
/usr/local/squid/sbin/squid -N -d 1 -D
```

Наслаждаемся результатом, то есть лезем в его логи:

```
cat /usr/local/squid/squid.out | more
```